How to get accurate FFT from given equations?
I am getting an output from NDSolve, which is like a trochoid curve and can be modelled like this:
coordrep = {t -> t[\[Tau]], r -> r[\[Tau]], 
   x -> x[\[Tau]], \[Theta] -> \[Theta][\[Tau]], t' -> t'[\[Tau]], 
   r' -> r'[\[Tau]], x' -> x'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]' -> \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]};

u0 = Log[2/5];

lagrangian = 
  E^(2 u0 + 2 a x^2)/(
     2/5) (-(t')^2 + T[x] (\[Theta]')^2 + (r')^2 - r^2 \[Alpha]^2) + (
     2 a^2 x^2)/T[x] (x')^2 /. coordrep;

Pt = D[lagrangian, t'[\[Tau]]];

Px = D[lagrangian, x'[\[Tau]]];

Pr = D[lagrangian, r'[\[Tau]]];

P\[Theta] = D[lagrangian, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]];

hamiltonian = ((Pt t'[\[Tau]] + Px x'[\[Tau]] + Pr r'[\[Tau]] + 
          P\[Theta] \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]) - 
        lagrangian) /. (Solve[{pt[\[Tau]] == Pt, px[\[Tau]] == Px, 
          pr[\[Tau]] == Pr, 
          p\[Theta][\[Tau]] == P\[Theta]}, {t'[\[Tau]], x'[\[Tau]], 
          r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]}] // Last) /. 
     pt[\[Tau]] -> En /. p\[Theta][\[Tau]] -> k // Expand;

equations = {x'[\[Tau]] == +D[hamiltonian, px[\[Tau]]], 
     r'[\[Tau]] == +D[hamiltonian, pr[\[Tau]]], 
     px'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, x[\[Tau]]], 
     pr'[\[Tau]] == -D[hamiltonian, r[\[Tau]]]} /. 
    pt[\[Tau]] -> En /. p\[Theta][\[Tau]] -> k;

ClearAll[habd, b, c, d, f]

T[x_] := 1 - E^(-5 a x^2)

a = 5/4; En = 0.22; k = 0.2; \[Alpha] = 1;

habd := hamiltonian /. \[Tau] -> 0 /. {x[0] -> b, px[0] -> c, 
    r[0] -> d, pr[0] -> f};

{b, c, d} = {1.1, 0, 0};

f = f /. Solve[habd == 0, f][[2]]

\[Tau]max = 1000;

sol = NDSolve[{equations, {x[0] == b, px[0] == c, r[0] == d, 
     pr[0] == f}}, {x, px, r, pr}, {\[Tau], 0, \[Tau]max, 0.01}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1/500, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]][[1]]

sr = 900;

data = Table[Evaluate[x[\[Tau]] /. sol[[1]]], {\[Tau], 0, 700, 1/sr}];

ft = Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];

ff = Table[(n - 1) sr/Length@data, {n, Length@data}];

ListLogPlot[Transpose[{ff, Abs[ft]}][[1 ;; 70]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.05}, Automatic}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency/Hz", "Spectral Level"}]

The question arose while working with Figure 1 of this paper(attached below), where one can get the exact details of the problem I am trying to solve.

I was able to get the FFT of the output, but now I have the issue that no matter how big the Sample Rate(sr) I take, I get a similar result like this:

How can I get the result of the image like Figure 1(b), as shown above? Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

For future, please note that deleting a question and posting the same question again is not really encouraged here :)

@Domen apologies :) Actually, I was not getting any response to my edit question; hence tried this illegal method :D

As for your problem: You will not achieve better frequency resolution just by increasing the sampling rate within the same time window. You have to increase the τmax (and then also the 700 inside data = Table[...]).

If your signal is periodic (as it appears to be) then you want to do a Fourier series expansion, rather than a Fourier transform.  Frequencies that are not multiples of the fundamental frequency should have zero power.  (The Fourier transform is actually a weighted comb of delta functions)

To get more resolution in the FFT, you need to take the transform over a longer period in time. Try setting τmax = 10000;. Do the solution over {τ, 0, τmax, 0.1}, and evaluate x[τ] over {τ, 0, 7000, 1/sr}.
With these values you get:

